# Displaying field name istead of ID in Attribute Form filter using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have three Postgresql layers:

1- item_line(id,geom,job_id)

2- job(id, name, status_id)

3- status(id, name)

In QGIS I have created two relations: one is between item_line and job, and the other is between job and status.

Then in the Attribute Form of the item_line layer, I configured it to show the job name instead of the job_id, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

And created a fitler on the job_id widget, based on the status_id, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

What I want is instead of showing the status_id in the filter combobox, I want to show the status name.

How to Do that?